# python xml parser with ElementTree amazon api

Tags: python, xml, nodes, amazon-product-api

I need some help to understand the ElementTree in python for iterate this xml string :

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" ?><BrowseNodeLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"><OperationRequest><HTTPHeaders><Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Python-urllib/3.5"/></HTTPHeaders><RequestId>54e05f2a-e792-11e5-8694-85b3fa7a9fcf</RequestId><Arguments><Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxx"/><Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxx-21"/><Argument Name="BrowseNodeId" Value="2844434031"/><Argument Name="Operation" Value="BrowseNodeLookup"/><Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/><Argument Name="Signature" Value="cf1A3M8S30Y32EdxVVoBljYUNrt4ZiqgvM+/B1uPrDg="/><Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2016-03-11T14:05:38Z"/><Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/></Arguments><RequestProcessingTime>0.005945883</RequestProcessingTime></OperationRequest><BrowseNodes><Request><IsValid>True</IsValid><BrowseNodeLookupRequest><BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId></BrowseNodeLookupRequest></Request><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Categorie</Name><IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot><Children><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892859031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Donna</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892862031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Uomo</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892857031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Bambine e ragazze</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892858031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Bambini e ragazzi</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>1739205031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Prima infanzia</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892860031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Abbigliamento specifico e altre marche</Name></BrowseNode></Children><Ancestors><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2844433031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Abbigliamento</Name></BrowseNode></Ancestors></BrowseNode></BrowseNodes></BrowseNodeLookupResponse>'
```

i need in output the children browsenodeid and the name :

```
children : 2892859031
name : Donna
children : 2892862031
name : Uomo
children : 2892857031
name : Bambine e ragazze
...
```

someone can help me to write a little script in python for parse this xml ?

Comment: The end point you are hitting, isn't it supported by official python wrapper (boto)  of amazon api? If it is then use that and you will automatically get data in dicts and lists by the wrapper.

Comment: yes it comes from an amazon request, but i don't know how to use it and i don't know really if boto works with this requests ... do you have any experience with this ?

Comment: What data exactly you are fetching from aws? Which endpoint / url you are hitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do this with python ElementTree, this can basically print the informations you're looking for. Works with recursion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root=ET.fromstring(b'<?xml version="1.0" ?><BrowseNodeLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"><OperationRequest><HTTPHeaders><Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Python-urllib/3.5"/></HTTPHeaders><RequestId>54e05f2a-e792-11e5-8694-85b3fa7a9fcf</RequestId><Arguments><Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxx"/><Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxx-21"/><Argument Name="BrowseNodeId" Value="2844434031"/><Argument Name="Operation" Value="BrowseNodeLookup"/><Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/><Argument Name="Signature" Value="cf1A3M8S30Y32EdxVVoBljYUNrt4ZiqgvM+/B1uPrDg="/><Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2016-03-11T14:05:38Z"/><Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/></Arguments><RequestProcessingTime>0.005945883</RequestProcessingTime></OperationRequest><BrowseNodes><Request><IsValid>True</IsValid><BrowseNodeLookupRequest><BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId></BrowseNodeLookupRequest></Request><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Categorie</Name><IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot><Children><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892859031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Donna</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892862031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Uomo</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892857031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Bambine e ragazze</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892858031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Bambini e ragazzi</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>1739205031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Prima infanzia</Name></BrowseNode><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2892860031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Abbigliamento specifico e altre marche</Name></BrowseNode></Children><Ancestors><BrowseNode><BrowseNodeId>2844433031</BrowseNodeId><Name>Abbigliamento</Name></BrowseNode></Ancestors></BrowseNode></BrowseNodes></BrowseNodeLookupResponse>')

# This AMAZON_STR is a kind of "header". It comes from xmls attribute of BrowseNodeLookupResponse (could be extracted from it, in case it changes in the future)
AMAZON_STR="{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}"

# Recursive function that deals with a node
def get_data_from(xml_node):
    # Loop over the children of current node
    for child in xml_node:
        # To avoid the "Category" Node, we only check the ones who have exactly 2 children
        if len(child) == 2:
            # We only look into the content of BrowseNode nodes
            if child.tag == AMAZON_STR + "BrowseNode":
                # Looping over the children of a BrowseNode node,
                # we simply print the contents (.text)
                for c in child:
                    if c.tag == AMAZON_STR + "BrowseNodeId":
                        print("children : " + c.text)
                    if c.tag == AMAZON_STR + "Name":
                        print("name : " + c.text)

        get_data_from(child)

# Finally call the function on the top node (root)
get_data_from(root)
```

Output:

```
$ ./test_script
children : 2892859031
name : Donna
children : 2892862031
name : Uomo
children : 2892857031
name : Bambine e ragazze
children : 2892858031
name : Bambini e ragazzi
children : 1739205031
name : Prima infanzia
children : 2892860031
name : Abbigliamento specifico e altre marche
children : 2844433031
name : Abbigliamento
```

Appendix:
The content of your xml string, once indented, is easier to understand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<BrowseNodeLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
    <OperationRequest>
        <HTTPHeaders>
            <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Python-urllib/3.5"/>
        </HTTPHeaders>
        <RequestId>54e05f2a-e792-11e5-8694-85b3fa7a9fcf</RequestId>
        <Arguments>
            <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxx"/>
            <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxx-21"/>
            <Argument Name="BrowseNodeId" Value="2844434031"/>
            <Argument Name="Operation" Value="BrowseNodeLookup"/>
            <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
            <Argument Name="Signature" Value="cf1A3M8S30Y32EdxVVoBljYUNrt4ZiqgvM+/B1uPrDg="/>
            <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2016-03-11T14:05:38Z"/>
            <Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
        </Arguments>
        <RequestProcessingTime>0.005945883</RequestProcessingTime>
    </OperationRequest>
    <BrowseNodes>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>True</IsValid>
            <BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
                <BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId>
            </BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
        </Request>
        <BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNodeId>2844434031</BrowseNodeId>
            <Name>Categorie</Name>
            <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
            <Children>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2892859031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Donna</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2892862031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Uomo</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2892857031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Bambine e ragazze</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2892858031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Bambini e ragazzi</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>1739205031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Prima infanzia</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2892860031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Abbigliamento specifico e altre marche</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
            </Children>
            <Ancestors>
                <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>2844433031</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Abbigliamento</Name>
                </BrowseNode>
            </Ancestors>
        </BrowseNode>
    </BrowseNodes>
</BrowseNodeLookupResponse>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer but when i run your code it returns nothing ... :(

Comment: oh, seems something got changed while I copied it. I check it

Comment: yes, the last line was missing, sorry, i edit this at once

Comment: thank you so much ... so now i have to understand your code :)

Comment: Edited my answer to provide some hints to understand it better.

Comment: Thank you so much ... you save me a day :)